# How can I display the font size and font type of text when reading with python-docx?

Tags: python, fonts, docx, python-docx

Basically I have started using the `python-docx` library for reading Word documents. So far, I have used the code below:

```
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        print (run.font.size)
```

However, this prints `None`. My question is:

How do i display the font size and font type of text?

Or if this is not possible then can I segregate all the text based on their format when I say format I mean font size, font type, if it is bold etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`run.font.size` reports `None` because there is no explicitly assigned size on that run. That is the expected behavior.

What I believe you are looking for is the "effective size", meaning the size at which it will appear in a document.

This is a challenging problem because in Word, that size is determined by inheritance in a multi-level *style hierarchy*, and that inheritance is governed by ill-documented rules.

For example, if this run is in a paragraph of 'Normal' style (the default), it may inherit its size from that style definition.

Calculating the effective value of size or any other font characteristic requires traversing its style hierarchy and applying the precedence rules. This functionality is not implemented in `python-docx`

Comment: is there any other library that I can use for deterimining the font size or may be how do I get the font size then